# How many number of mention entities can we add in adaptive cards?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Unable to mention more number of users in same adaptive card. Sometime it mentioning all the user but other time it is skipping few of them. And entities array contains all the users.

```
 async weeklyReportCard(text, entities) {
const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
  $schema: 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
  version: '1.0',
  type: 'AdaptiveCard',
  body: [
    {
      type: 'TextBlock',
      text,
      isSubtle: false,
      wrap: true,
    },
  ],
  msteams: {
    entities,
  },
});
return card;
```

},

where entities is an array of object containing list of users ->

```
entities.push({
      'type': 'mention',
      'text': `<at>${user.userName}</at>`,
      'mentioned': {
        'id': user.memberID,
        'name': user.userName,
      },
    });
```

and text =
`Hi <at>${user1.userName}</at>! <at>${user2.userName}</at>, <at>${user2.userName}</at>, <at>${user3.userName}</at>, <at>${user4.userName}</at>, <at>${user5.userName}</at>, <at>${user6.userName}</at>, <at>${user7.userName}</at>`

where userName of a user is the displayName

Comment: We could not repro the issue on our side. You mentioned that it works sometimes and does not work some other times. Do you see any changes in the users? Are all these users part of the same tenant? How are you trying to @mention them? Are they part of the same team?

Comment: Yes, all users are part of same tenant. I was sending a card to the user after every 10 min in which all these were mentioned. In adaptive card, I added the mentions through 'msteams' attribute.

Comment: Are all these users part of a team? How are you sending this card? Is it in a team where all these users are a part?